# Tables: font size setting for all the cells and \arraystretch

Tags: tables, spacing, fontsize

I'm trying to create tables with small font size text in cells and large space between rows.

If I put `\small` in every cell, the command

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
```

works, but if I try to put `\small` for all the table, it doesn't work anymore.

Is there a way to set small font size once for all the cells keeping the large space between rows?

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage[british,english]{babel}

\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,format=hang,indention=0cm]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=above, belowskip=4pt}

\begin{document}

%table with \small for all the table
\begin{table}[!h]
    \centering 
    \begin{threeparttable}[b]
        \caption{Table with \textbackslash{}small set once for all the cells}
        \small
            \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
                \toprule 
                \addlinespace
                        & Capital Elements\\
                \addlinespace
                \midrule
                Tier 1  & Paid-up share capital/common stock \\
                        & Disclosed reserves \\
                \addlinespace
                Tier 2  & Undisclosed reserves \\
                        & Asset revaluation reserves \\
                        & General provision/general loan-loss reserves \\
                        & Hybrid (debt/equity) capital instruments \\
                        & Subordinated debt \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \par        
        \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
            \footnotesize{}\emph{Source}: BCBS (1988).
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

%table with \small at every cell            
\begin{table}[!h]
    \centering 
    \begin{threeparttable}[b]
        \caption{Table with \textbackslash{}small set at every cell}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
        \toprule 
        \addlinespace
                            & {\small{}Capital Elements}\\
        \addlinespace
        \midrule
        {\small{}Tier 1}    & {\small{}Paid-up share capital/common stock}\\
                            & {\small{}Disclosed reserves}\\
        \addlinespace
        {\small{}Tier 2}    & {\small{}Undisclosed reserves}\\
                            & {\small{}Asset revaluation reserves}\\
                            & {\small{}General provision/general loan-loss reserves}\\
                            & {\small{}Hybrid (debt/equity) capital instruments}\\
                            & {\small{}Subordinated debt}\\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
            \footnotesize{}\emph{Source}: BCBS (1988).
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

And the output:

[image]

Comment: Your conclusion is wrong. Stretching works in both cases, however starting point is different. At common `\small` is considered line spacing (baseline) for small size font , at local placing of `\small` stretching still consider normal size fonts. So the baseline is higher as in the first case.

Comment: By the way, it is not necessary to encase the contents of each cell for which `\small` is in effect locally in curly braces: As the scope of `\small` is the cell itself, you could write `\small Tier 1` instead of `{\small{}Tier 1}` -- less code clutter, right?

Comment: Thank you, @Mico: I've copied the code from the source exported by LyX, that's way it so complicated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is normal: the result of `\arraystretch` depends on `\baselineskip`, which depends on the font size.

Instead of playing with `\arraystretch` you can load the `cellspace` package which defines minimal vertical spacing between a cell and the above and below cells.

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage[british,english]{babel}

\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,format=hang,indention=0cm]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=above, belowskip=4pt}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}

 \begin{document}

%table with \small for all the table
\begin{table}[!h]
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}[b]
        \caption{Table with \textbackslash{}footnotesize set once for all the cells and \textbackslash{}arraystretch = 1}
        \small
            \begin{tabular}{@{}SlSl@{}}
                \toprule
                \addlinespace
                        & Capital Elements\\
                \addlinespace
                \midrule
                Tier 1 & Paid-up share capital/common stock \\
                        & Disclosed reserves \\
                \addlinespace
                Tier 2 & Undisclosed reserves \\
                        & Asset revaluation reserves \\
                        & General provision/general loan-loss reserves \\
                        & Hybrid (debt/equity) capital instruments \\
                        & Subordinated debt \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \par
        \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
            \footnotesize{}\emph{Source}: BCBS (1988).
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

%table with \small at every cell
\begin{table}[!h]
    \centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \begin{threeparttable}[b]
        \caption{Table with \textbackslash{}small set at every cell and\\\textbackslash{}arraystretch = 1.3}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
        \toprule
        \addlinespace
                            & {\small{}Capital Elements}\\
        \addlinespace
        \midrule
        {\small{}Tier 1} & {\small{}Paid-up share capital/common stock}\\
                            & {\small{}Disclosed reserves}\\
        \addlinespace
        {\small{}Tier 2} & {\small{}Undisclosed reserves}\\
                            & {\small{}Asset revaluation reserves}\\
                            & {\small{}General provision/general loan-loss reserves}\\
                            & {\small{}Hybrid (debt/equity) capital instruments}\\
                            & {\small{}Subordinated debt}\\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
            \footnotesize{}\emph{Source}: BCBS (1988).
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As @Zarko and @Bernard have already pointed out, setting `\small` at the start of each cell is not the same as having `\small` apply to the entire row of a `tabular` environment: even though the cell contents will be typeset at the same size, the values of `\baselineskip` will differ. Specifically, given that the main font size of your document is `11pt`, the value of `\baselineskip` is `13.6pt` if `\normalsize` is in effect, while it is `12pt` if `\small` is in effect.

> Is there a way to set `\small` font size once for all cells keeping the large space between rows?

To make up for the difference in `\baselineskip`, you could increase the value of `\arraystretch` by a factor of 13.6/12=1.1333 for the table in which `\small` is in effect globally, i.e., set `\arraystretch` to 1.4733 for that table. The following screenshot shows that this is the correct adjustment amount. (Note that I've used `>{\small}l` as the column definition for the table on the right, saving me from having to type `\small` at the start of each and every cell.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage[british,english]{babel}

\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,
            labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,
            format=hang,indention=0cm]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=above, belowskip=4pt}

\newcommand\tabinterior[1]{% table interior is common to both tables
\toprule 
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{#1}\\
\addlinespace
\midrule
Tier 1  & Paid-up share capital \\
        & Disclosed reserves \\
\addlinespace
Tier 2  & Undisclosed reserves \\
        & Asset revaluation reserves \\
        & General provision/general \\
        & Hybrid (debt/equity) capital \\
        & Subordinated debt \\
\bottomrule}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}[!h]
\small
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4733}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} ll @{}}
\tabinterior{\textbackslash small global for entire table}
\end{tabular}
\normalsize % back to '11pt' as the main font size
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3} 
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} *{2}{>{\small}l} @{}}
\tabinterior{\textbackslash small local to each cell}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```